# Running RDPDFKitDemo_1.2

Tags: xcode

I have purchased reddle kit for ipad pdf viewer. when i try to run the demo program i am getting following error

```
Ld /Users/svp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RDPDFKitSample-gjablgzmrirtqteckhbcytapkwcc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RDPDFKitSample.app/RDPDFKitSample normal i386
cd /Users/svp/Desktop/RDPDFKitDemo_1_2
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-g++-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk -L/Users/svp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RDPDFKitSample-gjablgzmrirtqteckhbcytapkwcc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/svp/Desktop/RDPDFKitDemo_1_2/RDPDFKit.embeddedframework/RDPDFKit.framework/Versions/A -F/Users/svp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RDPDFKitSample-gjablgzmrirtqteckhbcytapkwcc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/svp/Desktop/RDPDFKitDemo_1_2/RDPDFKit.embeddedframework -filelist /Users/svp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RDPDFKitSample-gjablgzmrirtqteckhbcytapkwcc/Build/Intermediates/RDPDFKitSample.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RDPDFKitSample.build/Objects-normal/i386/RDPDFKitSample.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework SystemConfiguration -framework RDPDFKit -framework Security -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -lz -framework CoreText -framework MessageUI -weak_framework UIKit -weak_framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/svp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RDPDFKitSample-gjablgzmrirtqteckhbcytapkwcc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RDPDFKitSample.app/RDPDFKitSample

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSFileCoordinator", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in RDPDFKit(libRDPDFKit.a-i386-master.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIReferenceLibraryViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in RDPDFKit(libRDPDFKit.a-i386-master.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

how can i solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

We don't support building with iOS 4 SDK.
Make sure you are building with iOS 5 SDK. YOur application will still be able to run on device with iOS 4.0.

Danil Somsikov
Readdle Inc.